# Second JavaScript code is always overriding the first

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am using 2 separate JavaScript refs...see below...

```
    <script src="../scripts/jsKeyboard.js" type="text/jscript"></script>
<script src="../scripts/DOB_Validate.js" type="text/jscript"></script>
```

I am calling each Javascript through an onfocus event using two seperate asp:Textbox...see below:

```
<asp:Textbox id="txtFirstName" runat="server" onfocus="jsKeyboard.focus(this);clean(this);" placeholder="Touch Here To Enter First Name" autofocus top="50%"></asp:Textbox>

    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onfocus="board.focus(this);clean(this);" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" 
 maxlength="10" Width="5%"></asp:TextBox>
```

I have two scripts inside the head of the page that initialize the keyboard with the corresponding .js external ref (see two separate .js scripts above)...

Scripts inside head:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        board.init("virtualKeyboard");
    });
 </script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
         jsKeyboard.init("virtualKeyboard");
     });
 </script>
```

However...the second script inside the head is always overriding the other...

How can I fix this issue???  Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Both of your functions look exactly the same. I am going to assume you want the same functionality for both? If that's the case, you are hooking into the same element 'txtContent'. You need to have the other script hook into 'TextBox1'.

For txtContent:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function () {
             jsKeyboard.init("virtualKeyboard");
             $("#txtContent").val(initText);
         });

     </script>
```

And TextBox1:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
          board.init("virtualKeyboard");
          $("#TextBox1").val(initText);
      });

 </script>
```

You also may want to consider changing the name of TextBox1.